# Divs not hiding using prototype.js in IE only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I'm trying to do some fairly simple hide/show of divs using prototype.js. The page is working completely correctly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but one specific part won't work in IE: the initial hiding of divs. The page has three divs, and the javascript is written so that you can switch between them, with only one being displayed at a time. This part works fine in IE too, but for some reason, when the page is first loaded, it shows all 3 divs. I've tried many things to hide them, leaving me with this current incarnation:

The relevant HTML:

```
    <div class="linkbar">
        <a class='normal' href="JavaScript:void()" sec="map">Map</a><br><br>
        <a class='normal' href="JavaScript:void()" sec="tour">Tour</a><br><br>
        <a class='normal' href="JavaScript:void()" sec="vid">Videos</a><br><br>
    </div>

<div class="bg">
    <div class="section" id="map" sec="map">
        ...html here...
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="tour" sec="tour">
        ...html here...
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="vid" sec="vid">
        ...html here...
    </div>
</div>
```

The relevant Javascript:

```
 document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
    showSection("map");
    var currSection = 'map';

    $$('a.normal').each(function(p){
        Event.observe(p,'click',function(){
            var hr = $(this).readAttribute("sec");
            showSection(hr);
            currSection = hr;
        });
    });

    function showSection(sectionname){
        $$('div.section').each(function(d){
            d.hide();
        });
        $(sectionname).show();
    }
});

</script>
```

So in IE, as soon as I choose any of the links, it correctly hides the divs and then opens the correct one, which would indicate to me that it's able to find and hide the divs. However, when I first load the page in IE, it doesn't hide anything. Thoughts on why this is happening?

EDIT: Upon further research, I'm thinking this may relate to issues with IE and checking for DOM loading.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, and remove the `[Solved]` tag from the title. This is not a forum, but a Q&A site. Question-and-Answer, each in own own post.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Prototype.js was catching a stack overflow error, and then re-throwing that same error in the catch block. For some reason, in IE when this was thrown, the code doing the initial hiding was not called. I went into prototype.js and commented out the line in the catch block that was re-throwing the error (828) and things are working correctly now.